# Did soldiers wear helmets in the 19th century?

Tags: military, 19th-century, warfare, technology

When trying to do research in military history, I got interested in 19th century warfare. I know that they wore a lot of hats back then, but did they also wear helmets? I know that helmets existed at the time, but they were for miners, firefighters, and ceremonies. Has any military (modern of its time), wear helmets in the actual battles and combat?

Comment: Have you tried searching '19th century military helmets'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_helmet#History):

> Military use of helmets declined after 1670, and rifled firearms ended
> their use by foot soldiers after 1700 but the Napoleonic era saw
> ornate cavalry helmets reintroduced for cuirassiers and dragoons in
> some armies which continued to be used by French forces during World
> War I as late as 1915.
>
> World War I and its increased use of artillery renewed the need for
> steel helmets, with the French Adrian helmet and the British Brodie
> helmet being the first modern steel helmets used on the
> battlefield, soon followed by the adoption of similar steel
> helmets, such as the Stahlhelm by the other warring nations.
> Such helmets offered protection for the head from shrapnel and
> fragments.

From antiquity to the 17th century the helmets are very present although not everybody afforded them. At some point around 1670 they became useless against new firearms but kept their importance for cavalry, in part for decorative reasons, in part because cavalry remained more exposed to blade/sword attack. these are very conspicuous in Napoleonic era (early 19th century).

[French Napoleonic Dragoon Helmet  (1806 Pattern)](https://www.militaryheritage.com/helmet5.htm)

[image]

WW1 saw the rise of the "modern" steel helmet as a protection against omnipresent use of artillery with fragmentation shells.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickelhaube

Comment: This seems to rely on implicit assumptions, maybe shared with QOP, like ie that 'helmet=metal', or _partially_ 'helmet=bullet protection'? The list goes on, imo, to include not just Pickelhaube but also shako, bearskin and esp custodian/pith _helmet…?_ Lots of 'protection' for different threats: weather, sabres, shrapnel…

Comment: @LаngLаngС - helmet+war+19century="metal helmet" :)